# We have recently migrated to govcloud+ and no longer able to authenticate to scratch org using jwt from devhub as part of our CI

Tags: scratch-org, jwt, ci, auth, govcloud

Below is our auth approach into scrath orgs to allow us to login and serve them as part of a "scratch-org-pool-service".

```
export SFDX_AUDIENCE_URL="https://test.salesforce.com"
echo "RUN SFDX AUTHENTICATE COMMAND"
sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant --clientid $SF_DEVHUB_CLIENTID --jwtkeyfile $PATH_TO_KEY_FILE --username $SALESFORCE_USERNAME --instanceurl $SALESFORCE_INSTANCE_URL --setalias 'scratch_org'
```

I have been able to authenticate using the scratch org's instance url and not "https://test.salesforce.com" by adding a "export SFDX_AUDIENCE_URL="https://test.salesforce.com"

I have also tried removing the audience url and having "https://test.salesforce.com" be the instance url but no luck.

I am receiving "user hasn't approved this consumer"

We recently migrated to govcloud+. Many jobs with the cli seem slower but I have waited a day to ensure the scratch org info has been "replicated" to test.salesforce.com

Any ideas and insights are very much appreciated

Comment: I don't know the answer to this question, but I also don't quite understand the paragraph starting with "I have been able to authenticate..." - are you able to rephrase for clarity?

Comment: thank you @DavidReed, in the documentation it says to use "https://test.salesforce.com" as the instanceurl. I have previously been able to use the url of the specific scratch org i am trying to authenticate to like "https://java-site-9993-dev-ed.cs133.my.salesforce.com/"
here is the doc i'm referring to (further down the page for the reference) - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_auth_jwt_flow.htm